# Javamelody monitor Tomcat overall

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

I followed the Tutorial [Deployment on Tomcat without modification of monitored webapps (beta)](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#deployment-on-tomcat-without-modification-of-monitored-webapps-beta). The Monitoring Site is working, I can see the statistics page. The Problem ist Javanmelody recognizes only the pages itself and the tomcat manager. But none of the deployments pages gets recognized. What can I do that Javamelody is monitoring all deployments? The Tomcat 9 has about 50 deployments. I want to see statistics about all deploments not just one deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with the [optional collect server](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#optional-centralization-server-setup). I have to add every URL seperated by **,** in one go. But it is only possible to monitor aggregated statistics about all deployments or one by one, but not [both](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/839).